# Can we evaluate life, existence and/or consciousness itself according to criteria that exist within it?

Tags: ontology, meaning

The idea of a criteria, of evaluation, of meaning, of assigning characteristics, of judging things as positive or negative or neutral, only exists as a subset of existence as far as I can tell. In fact, it seems to be associated only with certain types of existing phenomena such as conscious beings. Can we apply those ideas to existence itself if they are a subset of it?

As a very simple example: let's a say a person concludes that life itself is good or evil: are they committing a categorical error?

Comment: Not a bad question, actually Max Scheler discusses this very issue in various works. Unfortunately, I fear the answers that will be posted will be highly opinionated.

Comment: "Only exists as a subset of existence" sounds strange, existence is not a set and it has no subsets. It is a concept  and concepts can, in principle, be applied to themselves or other concepts they fall under. That "good" emerges from judgments of conscious beings does not, by itself, preclude it from having objective status. "Conscious", as we use it, and the rest also emerge from such judgments. We do not hesitate to apply "conscious" to ourselves, so why not "good" to "life"? There is no category error in that alone, at least, not based on this argument.